# Set a timer in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I'm trying to set a timeout before executing `form.submit()`but it doesn't work.

```
$("#form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $("#form").hide();
        $('#form-inscription').append('<h2>Text</h2>');
        setTimout( function(){ form.submit() }, 10000 );
        //form.submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Where do you define the variable `form`?

Comment: Typo in question `setTimout` ???

Comment: if you're using jquery validate then you need to set the object key to specify not submitting the form, also return false from submit handler

Comment: Add `var setTimout = setTimeout` in the beginning. ^^

Comment: I mean it tells me that form.submit() is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ticks = 0;
$("#form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $("#form").hide();
        $('#form-inscription').append('<h2>Text</h2>');
        ticks = 0;
        submitter(form); //this is your timer function 
    }
});

function submitter(form)
{
  if(ticks < 10)
  {
    ticks++;
    timer = setTimout(new function(){ submitter(form); }, 1000 );
   }
   else
  {
     form.submit();
     clearTimeout(timer);
   }
 }
```

Comment: You shoud pass form object as parameter in submitter as well, If you can't access form outside validate function

Comment: Thanks for answering,
So it would looks like this : submitter(form) ?

Comment: I have updated, try latest one and let me know if this still not works,

Comment: @securedeveloper You copied the mentioned typo with `setTimout`.

Comment: Thanks but there's always this problem related in the console log :
`TypeError: form.submit is not a function
form.submit();`

Comment: Ok corrected. Now the console log says :
`ReferenceError: timer is not defined
clearTimeout(timer);`

Comment: ok, You should also declare timer as global variable, like,

var ticks = 0;
var timer ;
$("#form").validate({ ....................... nd remaining line of code,

Comment: Actualy I cannot declare an unexistant function : if I declare `timer = setTimeout(new function(){ submitter(form); }, 1000 );` before the validation function, it'll fail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
var ticks = 0;
var timer=null;
$("#form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $("#form").hide();
        $('#form-inscription').append('<h2>Text</h2>');
        ticks = 0;
        submitter(); //this is your timer function 
    }
});

function submitter()
{
  if(ticks < 10)
  {
    ticks++;
    timer = setTimout("submitter()", 1000 );
   }
   else
  {
     $("#form").submit();
     clearTimeout(timer);
   }
 }
```